# CGAL How can I tell if triangle is on the boundary

Tags: c++, graphics, cgal

I'd like to be able to extract vertices of each edge on the triangulation boundary. The thing is that I first define constrained triangulation by defining constraints and holes in domain if necessary. Then I need to refine mesh via mesh refinement algorithm. It all works nice and dandy, except for one glitch. I have to tell which edge lies on which boundary. Let me give you an example: Given 4 polylines that define the domain, and are constraints in triangulation, (say top, bottom, left and right polyline), I have to tell wich edge lies on which polyline. I had defined each polyline as std::vector, which can be easily probed for point on segment. Like this:
CDT::Point pt1; CDT::Point pt2;

```
for(const auto& seg : segments)
{
  if(seg.has_on(pt1))
  { num++; }
  if(seg.has_on(pt2))
  { num++; }
  if(num==2){/*success? -> return true*/}              
}
```

I'm aware of CGAL::bounded_side_2 function, which sadly operates on polygons. How can I solve this problem?

```
for(CDT::Finite_edges_iterator it = cdt.finite_edges_begin();
            it != cdt.finite_edges_end(); ++it)
{
        CDT::Edge e=*it;
        // how can I tell if an edge is on boundary?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [is_contrained](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/classCGAL_1_1Constrained__triangulation__2.html#a1023bade959e2ff5a224d1bbd10a48a1) method from the constrained triangulation.

```
if (cdt.is_constrained(e)) ...
```

If you can have dandling edges, you must first mark the domain like in the following [example](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/index.html#title29) and check that the edge is incident to two faces that have different `nesting_level`.

Comment: how can I find which mesh refinement edge lays on which constrained edge before refinement? Is segment_2::has_on the right way to go? Or there is some other way?

Comment: I think if you wrap your contrained Delaunay triangulation into [this class](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/classCGAL_1_1Constrained__triangulation__plus__2.html) you will have access to the information (points added on constraints define sub-constraints).

Comment: indeed. Now I don't need to ask if an edge is constrained, since I iterate over constrained edges with Subconstraint_iterator. sorry for slow feedback